# Magento Get Product collection based on product name content first letter as digit

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to get product collections of all products which start digit as number like "0Pro","1Pro","3Pro","4Pro" and "41Pro" etc.,means it's first character must me a digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//the code below will build a condition like
//where (name like '0%' or name like '1%' or .... or name like '9%')
$condition = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<=9;$i++) {
    $condition[] = array('attribute'=>'name', 'like'=>$i.'%');
}
//get the product collection and apply the filter built above
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter($condition);

//loop through the collection.
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //do something with $product
}
```

You can use a regular expression but I'm really bad at them.
Something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=>'name', 'regexp'=>'^[0-9](.*)'));
```

but most probably I got the regular expression wrong.

Comment: it's okay thank you for your reply. i got my ans i did some modification with your code and i got my solutions. i have this solutions but i am try some general solutions i through it might me not good solution but if i don't get another than i will definitely used code something like what you answered.

Comment: Regex looks fine - 1 numeric character at the start of the string followed by anything.  You don't actually need the brackets around `.*` but it doesn't make any difference them being there.